# Pass form-data file along with request body with JSON value

Tags: node.js

I have written middleware by using multer

```
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const storage = multer.diskStorage({   
destination: (req, file, cb) => {       
    cb(null, 'uploads');
},
filename: (req, file, cb) => {        
    cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
}
});
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
if (file.mimetype == 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype == 'image/png' || file.mimetype == 'image/gif') {
    cb(null, true);
} else {
    cb(null, false);
}
}
const upload = multer({ storage: storage, fileFilter: fileFilter });
module.exports = upload;
```

And the I am using this is route

```
router.post('/adddata', multerUpload.single('profile_pic'),verifySession,addDataController.adddata);
```

When I call this API from POSTMAN we get the `req.file` but we didn't get `req.body` but we pass `req.body` also in payload